# Using .htaccess to Execute php if directory of the same name not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to execute php if directory of the same name not found.It works well on Wamp because it's already configured in its Apache httpd.conf but I don't know what to do with .htaccess.
EX: www.example.com/directory1/directory2/...../....... 
Actually There's no directory1 folder in the root but there's only a php file name "directory1.php"
 so I want www.example.com/directory1/directory2/ to execute a php file name "directory1.php"
 if the folder of that name is not found.
In Short, If there's a folder it'll follow that folder directory but if no folder then it'll execute the first directory which is in php file after website url without .php extension.
 So That php should be able to execute with slash behind "www.example.com/directory1/" or without slash "www.example.com/directory1".

Comment: The majority of configurations can be ported from the httpd.conf to the .htaccess.  Take your WAMP config section that enables that and try it in .htaccess.  If it does not work, post it here, **then** we can have a look.  You have to try and research first.

Comment: I had tried to researched already but There's not only 1 or 2 lines in that config file so I wouldn't know which 1 and I don't understand those config because I haven't never known it before, New.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the requested URL neither a directory nor a file, then rewrite to the PHP file with the Name of the first folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+) $1.php
```

Comment: Thank you, It works but I just don't understand its language because It's new to me.

Comment: I want to go back to index.php if there's no such php file and directory